# Uniqueness validation with transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use transaction to save Hotel model. Here is a code:

```
def init
  Hotel.transaction do
    @hotel.save!
    create_related_models
  end
end
```

I have uniqueness validation on `:name` in hotel. Validation isn't work inside transaction. What is the way of implementing database related validations inside a transaction?

Explanation why validation not work.

When user submit a form then request takes about 10s. If he click another time (on save button) during request then he will save two hotels with the same name(which is issue). It is because first transaction didn't finish, when another transaction start. So when another start there is no hotel in database so validation return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to either:

1. Add a database constraint to prevent this behaviour, and catch and handle any error. The application cannot have visibility of un-committed RDBMS transactions. Only the database can do that.
2. Add a locking mechanism in the application, which will be difficult if you are running on multiple threads (Heroku dynos?).
3. Greatly reduce the time taken for the transaction.
4. Move the creation of the related models outside of the transaction, and provide a mechanism for manually deleting the Hotel record is a problem arises during execution.
5. Remove the uniqueness validation.

Comment: I wanted to add locking mechanism but it turned out too difficult. Thanks for all solution. Currently I added javascript button block, but i also will implement your first solution (constrain and handle error)